# How to stop navigation menu from shrinking on WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress

The navigation menu on my WordPress website shrinks on random pages. When refreshing the page, the menu goes back to normal. How can I stop the menu from shrinking?

Comment: It is more or less impossible to answer this question without you showing the related html and css.

Comment: Can you provide the site url?

Comment: Site URL:  https://www.onlineairandsolar.com.au/